# Supabase Auth: Accessing Provider Information in Supabase's new Response Object

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I have set up a Supabase table, function, and trigger to handle new user creations. However, I am only able to access the provider_id from the new object in the trigger function. I would like to know if there is a way to access the entire provider information, such as google, discord, or other providers, instead of just the provider_id.

**Supabase Table and Trigger Setup:**

```sql
-- Table
create table users (
    id uuid references auth.users not null primary key,
    email text null,
    avatar text null,
    username text null,
    fullname text null,
    provider json null,
    provider_id text null,
    constraint users_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint users_id_fkey foreign key (id) references auth.users (id)
);

-- Function
create or replace function public.handle_new_user() 
returns trigger as $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO public.users (
    id,
    email,
    avatar,
    username,
    fullname,
    provider,
    provider_id
  )
  VALUES (
    new.id,
    new.email,
    jsonb_extract_path_text(new.raw_user_meta_data, 'avatar_url'),
    jsonb_extract_path_text(new.raw_user_meta_data, 'name'),
    jsonb_extract_path_text(new.raw_user_meta_data, 'full_name'),
    new.raw_user_meta_data,
    jsonb_extract_path_text(new.raw_user_meta_data, 'provider_id')
  );
  RETURN new;
END;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;

-- Trigger
create trigger on_auth_user_created
  after insert on auth.users
  for each row execute procedure public.handle_new_user();
```

**Supabase Output:**
When using the useUser() function from @supabase/auth-helpers-react in my code and logging the user object, I receive the following output:
[image: json session output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue/problem is already solved, Found out it is located at `raw_app_meta_data` it is similar to `raw_user_meta_data` that i have used.

So here's the updated function that I did:

```sql
BEGIN
  -- Insert the values into the public.users table
  INSERT INTO public.users (
    id,
    email,
    avatar,
    username,
    fullname,
    provider,
    provider_id
  )
  VALUES (
    new.id,
    new.email,
    jsonb_extract_path_text(new.raw_user_meta_data, 'avatar_url'),
    jsonb_extract_path_text(new.raw_user_meta_data, 'name'),
    jsonb_extract_path_text(new.raw_user_meta_data, 'full_name'),
    jsonb_extract_path_text(new.raw_app_meta_data, 'provider'),
    jsonb_extract_path_text(new.raw_user_meta_data, 'provider_id')
  );
  RETURN new;
END;
```